# How can I find a string like str contains substring subStr?

Tags: string, go

I have a string like `cars` and another one like `acasras`.
When some characters in my string are deleted, both contain a substring like `car`.

How can I check it in Go?

I tried using `strings.Contains(str, subStr)`, but it just includes strings like `cars`. I want to detect `cars` in a string like `acasras` too.

In summary, `contain(str, subStr)` should detect all `^c^a^r^` where `^` is any number of characters.

Comment: You just need to figure out what regular expression you want to use to capture this, and then use Go's built-in regular expressions: https://gobyexample.com/regular-expressions

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a recursive way of doing it:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(isInside("something", "")) // true
    fmt.Println(isInside("acasras", "cars")) // true
    fmt.Println(isInside("acasras", "cacs")) // false
}

func isInside(str, subStr string) bool {
    if len(subStr) == 0 {
        return true
    }
    head := getHead(subStr)
    tail := getTail(subStr)
    if strings.Contains(str, head) {
        return isInside(str[strings.Index(str, head)+1:], tail)
    }
    return false
}

func getHead(s string) string {
    if len(s) == 0 {
        return ""
    }
    return string(s[0])
}

func getTail(s string) string {
    if len(s) == 0 || len(s) == 1 {
        return ""
    }
    return string(s[1:])
}
```